# i need to connect ultrasonic gas MQ2 and IR sensor(as blink counter) to count the number of blinks

Tags: arduino-uno

im making a drowsiness detection using IR sensor as blink counter less than 30 and ultrasonic sensor distance should be less than 50cm and gas sensor MQ2 if the driver has consumed alcohol the gas will be detected and buzzer will be turned on and if the driver is drowsy the arduino will count the blinks if less than 30 it will turn on the buzzer and display on LCD as drowsy driver and led will blink.
can anyone pls help me with the codes?

i have managed the code

```
int trigPin = 6;
int echoPin = 7;
int IRSensor = 2; //connect ir sensor to arduino pin 2
int LED = 13;
int LED1 = 12;
int buzzer = 10;
int smokeA0 = A5;
int sensorThreshold = 50;
int sound=250;

void setup() {
  pinMode(trigPin,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin,INPUT);
  pinMode( IRSensor,INPUT);//sensor pin INPUT
  pinMode(LED1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);//LED pin OUTPUT
  pinMode(buzzer, OUTPUT);//Buzzer Pin OUTPUT
  pinMode(smokeA0, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() 
{
  long duration,distance,statusSensor;

  int IRSensor = digitalRead(IRSensor);
  int analogSensor = analogRead(smokeA0);
  Serial.print("Pin 2"); 
  Serial.println(statusSensor);
  Serial.print("Pin A0: ");
  Serial.println(analogSensor);
  // Checks if it has reached the threshold value
  if (distance<=30)
  if (statusSensor == 10)
  if (analogSensor > sensorThreshold)
  {
    digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LED1, LOW);
    tone(buzzer, 1000, 200);
  }


  else
  {
    digitalWrite(LED1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LED1, HIGH);
    noTone(buzzer);
  }
  digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LED1, LOW);
    tone(buzzer, 1000, 200);
  }


  else
  {
    digitalWrite(LED1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LED1, HIGH);
    noTone(buzzer);
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LED1, LOW);
    tone(buzzer, 1000, 200);
  }

 else
  {
    digitalWrite(LED1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LED1, HIGH);
    noTone(buzzer);
  }
  delay(100);
}
```

Comment: And what exactly is your problem?

Comment: You cannot use multiple else statements, but probably you want to have conditions there 'else if (condition)', except for the last else maybe.

Comment: what does `less than 30` mean?